# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: and pushing view controlle.r

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

My app is is designed to handle the PDF files. Whenever user opens a PDF file I would like to redirect the him/her to appropriate ViewController.

I tried several different approaches and I noticed interesting behavior.

Whenever I reference the navigation controller using window everything works fine:

```
  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [navigationController pushViewController:_importer animated:YES];
```

But when I use storyboard

```
 UIStoryboard *st =    [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController * nav =(UINavigationController *)[ st instantiateInitialViewController ];
[nav pushViewController:_importer animated:YES];
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instantiateInitialViewController` creates a new instance of the initial view controller of your storyboard. At that point, its view is not part of the view hierarchy. The pushing works just fine, I'm sure, but since the navigation controller isn't on screen, you won't see the new view controller get pushed.

Comment: So how come it works when I am using  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
?

Comment: Because `self.window.rootViewController` is set to the app's initial view controller. It's defined in (or if you use a storyboard before) `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and then shown on screen.